# ¿Cómo puedo implementar una condición en un WHERE y dependiendo de ese dato establecer la cantidad a mostrar?

Tags: mysql, sql

Requiero que en una consulta SQL se establezca una condición en el `WHERE` que dependiendo del resultado de ese dato me muestre un sólo resultado de este tipo de dato pero todos los demás ajenos a dicho resultado.

Esta es la sentencia actual:

```
SELECT * FROM productos as p 
WHERE visible='1' AND tipo_producto='0' AND estado='1' 
ORDER BY nombre ASC LIMIT 24 offset 2
```

Este es el esquema de la sentencia que requiero:

```
SELECT *  FROM productos as p 
WHERE visible='1' 
AND estado='1' IF(AND tipo_producto='1', LIMIT 1, LIMIT 24) 
ORDER BY precio_venta ASC LIMIT 1 offset 3;
```

Cabe resaltar que el `LIMIT` es sólo un ejemplo de la cantidad de resultados que necesito por cada *tipo_producto*, es decir: si existen 10 `tipo_producto = '1'` que sólo me muestre el menor de esos 10 y que me muestre el resto totalizado de los `tipo_producto = '0'`.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. A tu pregunta le vendría bien un ejemplo de la salida que buscas, que ayudaría a entender tu explicación. A veces los datos dicen más que 1000 palabras.

Comment: Tal y como mencionan, que datos tienes, que datos quieres, y que te muestra actualmente la 2da query

Comment: Esto no se entiende ni se ve reflejado así en la consulta que estás intentando: *si existen 10 tipo_producto = '1' que sólo me muestre el menor de esos 10 y que me muestre el resto totalizado de los tipo_producto = '0'*

Comment: Gracias por su participación.
Aclaro; La segunda consulta es sólo un ejemplo, la verdad no tengo idea de cómo obtener el resultado.

El resultado que espero es el siguiente:
Si tengo 10 productos tipo 1 que me muestre el menor de esos productos ordenado por precio, y al mismo tiempo que me muestre todos los productos que son tipo 0 en el mismo orden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta básicamente se centraba en realizar un condicional y tomando el resultado de este condicional mostrar los resultados. Aunque este tipo de resultados es mejor manejarlos desde el código propio en el lenguaje que se esté realizando, pero para dar respuesta se resume en lo siguiente:

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT nombre FROM productos as a  WHERE a.id = br.id) as producto, 
   IF(tipo_producto="1", "Venta", "descartado") as estado, 
   precio_venta,
   id 
FROM `productos` as br HAVING estado = "Venta" ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

De verdad gracias a los que participaron.

Comment: Comentario que eliminaré en breve: gracias por responder a tu pregunta y aceptarla por más de que haya pasado tanto tiempo <3